Why is it considered okay to use structs to represent MMIO registers in embedded system firmware, but not bit fields?
In embedded system firmware, it's common to represent multiple memory-mapped registers of a peripheral using a struct, under the assumption that compiler's code generation will follow a particular memory layout on a given platform. For example, the following code is standard:
typedef struct
{
    volatile uint32_t CRL;  /* bytes  0 to  4 */
    volatile uint32_t CRH;  /* bytes  4 to  8 */
    volatile uint32_t IDR;  /* bytes  8 to 12 */
    volatile uint32_t ODR;  /* bytes 12 to 16 */
} GPIO_t;

#define GPIOA         ((GPIO_t *) 0xDEADBEEF)
#define GPIOB         ((GPIO_t *) 0xDEADCODE)

void loop(void)
{
    GPIOB->CRL = 0x01;
    GPIOA->CRH = 0x01;
}

The justifications of this method are:

It creates a simulated namespace in plain C code. Different GPIO ports can have the same registers, but they're clearly distinguished without using ugly prefixes, and the peripheral structs can be directly passed around as a whole.

Repeated register layouts only need to be defined once.

Although the C standard has few requirements (if any) on the exact memory layout of structs, they're usually predictable on a given platform. Since all registers are MCU-specific anyway, portability is unimportant.


Thus, it's my impression that this technique is common.
To represent fields within a physical MMIO register, using bit fields in a struct is a closely related technique that can achieve similar results. For example, the bit fields in the CRH register may be represented using the following struct:
typedef struct
{
    /* 
     * 00: Analog Input, 01: Floating Input
     * 10: Pull-up/down, 11: Reserved
     */
    volatile unsigned int CTL7  : 2; 

    /* 00: Pull Pull,    01: Open Drain */
    volatile unsigned int MODE7 : 2; 

    volatile unsigned int CTL6  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE6 : 2;
    volatile unsigned int CTL5  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE5 : 2;
    volatile unsigned int CTL4  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE4 : 2;
    volatile unsigned int CTL3  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE3 : 2;
    volatile unsigned int CTL2  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE2 : 2;
    volatile unsigned int CTL1  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE1 : 2;
    volatile unsigned int CTL0  : 2;
    volatile unsigned int MODE0 : 2;
} CRH_t;

Questions:

In low-level embedded firmware, is it considered acceptable to represent multiple MMIO registers using a struct?

In low-level embedded firmware, is it considered acceptable to represent multiple options within the same register using bit fields in structs?

Both techniques are related, and both rely on potentially unportable assumptions. But it appears to me that the answer to the first question is often "YES", but the answer to the second question is often "NO" - or at least with considerable disagreements. For example, in question Is it ok to use bit-fields in embedded system firmware?, many objections can be found:

Lundin: It's naive to think you'll never have to port the program. Quite a few programs will have to get ported to a different compiler at some point, even if the hardware stays the same. Especially true for embedded systems. In addition, it is quite nice to be able to re-use already written code in new projects. I can mention at least 10 more [compilers]. And then different hardware ports of all those compilers. They do not implement padding, endianess or even bit order the same. They are all quite different with how they handle bit padding when you mix different types in the same struct.
Another aspect: I've written plenty of simulators and test cases for my MCU programs on a 64 bit PC. For example at one point I designed a radio spectrum allocation algorithm and needed a graphical simulator to visualize and debug the algorithm. The target platform was a 8 bit MCU but I ran all tests on 64 bit x86. To do the same by hacking together some LCD graphics library + fixing hardware for it would have been way more time consuming than writing portable code and then hack together a simple Windows app in a RAD tool.

Why is it considered okay to use structs to represent MMIO registers in embedded system firmware, but not bit fields?




bit fields are liable to be less portable. 2) Changing multiple bit fields mapped to one register could take multiple writes. Not only undesirable, but a potential problem if the fields should be changed at the same time. 3) Writing to a bit field requires a read, modification of value, and a write. Extra read may be undesirable or break things. beyond that, some registers are write only; some are different registers depending on reading or writing the address; some are multiple registers at the same address and cycle which you get each time you access the address.


@AviBerger Yes, I'm aware of the read-modify-write problem. In one project I've seen, the library provides both bit fields and macro definitions simultaneously. Atomic multiple fields changes can be done using macros, but trivial single-field reads and writes are done in bit fields for brevity and readability.

Summary: it depends on the situation how feasible and appropriate it might be.

Just my 2 cents, short of an actual answer: The order in a struct is defined, the padding is not defined, and the order/endianness of bit fields is not defined.

@AviBerger If RMW will cause errors or problems, I'd consider it an error to define bit fields for a register.

I don't think you can make that general assertion of all embedded systems or target architectures.  There are plenty of examples where bit-fields are used as you have described, but I would advise using that only where vendor supplied headers included with the toolchain are provided, where the implementation-defined behaviour is known and has been taken into account.

The important part is in Lundin's quote: In a struct, the members are always allocated in order (and you can assert on the size to verify no padding). On the other hand, when asking for 2 bits in a bit field, you don't know which two bits you get. Different compilers do make different choices.

An example for PIC18 supplied with SDCC: https://github.com/gheja/sdcc/blob/master/sdcc/device/non-free/include/pic16/pic18f2550.h.  It is done, but you should not do it yourself, and it will limit portability across toolchains.  You cannot simply reuse that header with a different toolchain and guarantee it will work.  You need one for the toolchain.

@Clifford What if I'm writing my own HAL in place of the vendor-supplied one? So in the end, it seems that the only reason not to use bit field is merely a matter of responsibility (or the avoidance of it). If the HAL is provided by the vendor or the toolchain, it's their job to guarantee that bit fields are working, including any necessary porting if incompatibility arises between toolchains. But if I'm doing it on my own, then it becomes my own problem - most programmers would want to delegate this responsibility to the vendors/toolchain makers - and this is the entire reason.

@Clifford Having programmed PIC16 before, I know for sure that bit fields are used, in fact this programming style is officially endorsed by the vendor, and all routines in officially datasheets and application notes make use of them. All reasonable toolchains are expected to provide an working implementation if they want to remain compatibility with the official programming style...

@比尔盖子 "What if I'm writing my own HAL in place of the vendor-supplied one?". A HAL and a register map are not the same thing.  Go ahead write your own HAL, but use the vendor supplied register map header to do it.

@比尔盖子 - "I know for sure that bit fields are used"; yes, that was my point.  It was a follow in from my earlier point.  The link is to the header clearly showing the use of bit-fields. You are now contradicting yourself since in the question you suggest it is not done.

@Clifford No, I'm not contradicting myself! I'm contracting other experts on Stack Overflow! Personally, I think bit fields are as acceptable as structs with assumed memory layouts - not exactly portable, but works okay in practice. But oddly, according to what I've read online - including Stack Overflow, the general opinion is that bit fields are much more unpopular than structs, and I'm puzzled by their objections. This is the motivation behind this question - an invitation for these developers to explain reasons behind these objections. Your given example only strengths my question.

@比尔盖子. To clarify, you state in the question title that use of bit-fields for this purpose is not considered acceptable.  Then you stated in the comment that you are aware if situations where it is accepted.  Both ways - a contradiction.  It is not universally true that it is unacceptable, but you are emphatic that it is in the question.

The memory layout of a strict in terms of order is well defined.  Alignment is implementation defined, but the alignment is likely to be the same as the register alignment since that is exactly why it is implementation defined - to match platform natural alignment.  Bitfield alignment and order has greater potential for variation and arbitrary implementation decisions.

bit fields representation is different from one machine to another, especially regarding endianness (the order in which bytes are stored), some machines write numerals with the most significant digits on the left, so we might consider bit 31 to be the leftmost and bit 0 to be the rightmost,
but when you use structs to represent MMIO registers in embedded systems, the compiler ensures that the structure's fields are arranged correctly according to the target machine's architecture.
for example:
let's suppose we have this struct:
struct Data {
    int number1; //(4 bytes)
    int number2; //(4 bytes)
};

and we have two machines first one is Big Endian second one is Little Endian
sending a struct:-
1- Sender Machine (Big Endian):
Data dataToSend = {123, 456};

2- Receiver Machine (Little Endian):
Data dataReceived = {123, 456};

sending a bits:-
1- Sender Machine (Big Endian):
sends (00 00 00 7B 00 00 01 C8)

number1 (4 bytes): 00 00 00 7B (hexadecimal for 123)

number2 (4 bytes): 00 00 01 C8 (hexadecimal for 456)

1- Receiver Machine (Little Endian):
received (00 00 00 7B 00 00 01 C8)

number1 (4 bytes): 00 00 00 7B (hexadecimal for 2063597568)

number2 (4 bytes): 00 00 01 C8 (hexadecimal for 3355508736)

note:
if you want the receiver to get the bits correctly it should be sent like this:
7B 00 00 00 C8 01 00 00

Also, note that if both machines are big-endian or both are little-endian, then bits sending is valid. or if you perform a transformation from big-endian to little-endian when you receive the data with adding an extra parameter indicating your machine type, it can also work. or send a struct and let the compiler do the work.

Just to clarify a point... The communication protocol must have an agreed upon endianness regardless of the endianness of the actual machines, right?

no, the endianness of machines is important to know, plus it is hard to change endianness across all the machines all over the world, both endianness are fine, sending data is already a solved thing, usually with bits sending they are adding the machine type so that the receiver machine can do the needed transformation. plus even if the two machines have the same bits order, there is still more to consider.
